# How to add javascript with #attached in a node which contains a specific paragraph bundle

Tags: 7, javascript

I need to attach js in all nodes with a specif paragraph bundle. I know how to do this with drupal_add_js, but I prefer don't use it to prevent cache problems.

I am trying with hook preprocess_entity but I don't get it, I don't know how to use the ["#attached"]

```
function THEME_preprocess_entity(&$variables) { 
  if (isset($variables['paragraphs_item']->bundle) && variables['paragraphs_item']->bundle == "XXXXX") {
   $variables["elements"]["#attached"]['js'][] = array(
                'type' => 'file',
                'data' => 'myfile.js',
              );
      }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `I don't know how to use the ["#attached"]` did you refer to the Drupal 7 documentation on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got, I have to add ['content'] before ['#attached']

```
function THEME_preprocess_entity(&$variables) { 
  if (isset($variables['paragraphs_item']->bundle) && variables['paragraphs_item']->bundle == "XXXXX") {
    $variables["content"]["#attached"]['js'][] = array(
       'type' => 'file',
       'data' => 'myFile.js',
    );
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for attaching

```
$variables['#attached']['js'][] = 'myfile.js';
```

Or

```
$variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'myfile.js';
```

Comment: Thanks to answer me, but don't works